# motion tracking : How to apply lens distortion value from one clip to another?

Tags: tracking, distort

I tried to track a distorted clip using motion tracker. I already determined the distortion value K1,K2 using a reference grid. Now I need to apply this distortion value to other clip. How can I do this without manually copy/pasting the value (K1,K2,k3, optical center)? If I open a new clip, this value will be reset to 0.

There should be a way to transfer this values across the clips because by default the clip to track and the reference grid will be in separated files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The lens distortion values (and all tracking information for that matter) are uniquely associated with the clip that was loaded in the clip editor.

The distortion information can be accessed in the compositor via the Distort>**Movie Distortion** node. There you can assign distortion undistortion and unsdistortion to different elements. The file that contains the undistortion info can be selected there.

[image]

Note that the information from the compositor will not be reflected in the Movie Clip Editor. If you must see the undistorted information on the Movie Clip Editor, then you will have to input those values manually.