# Using distortion grids

Tags: camera, tracking

Hi I'm planning to use blender for some vfx stuff and I'd like to use distortion grid to generate lens distortion profile, is it possible unside blender or maybe use pftrack to do that? Actually pftrack seems to be working for me but i think that distortion models are not the same, so help me figure out this question, please.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133722/motion-tracking-how-to-apply-lens-distortion-value-from-one-clip-to-another

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine lens undistortion values for motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/how-to-determine-lens-undistortion-values-for-motion-tracking)